# Using Cloud Vision REST Api for blur detection instead of Firebase vision api

Tags: android, firebase, blur, google-cloud-vision, firebase-mlkit

In my application I need to detect blurriness of images.

So firstly , is it possible using Google Cloud Vision api which I think is as given here 
*https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate*

Also most of the applications on cloud vision are available to Android development through Firebase ML vision apis with the following dependency

*com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.2*

I did tried FirebaseVision's VisionFaceDetector and even TextRecognizer in my app but it wasn't useful considering the it didn't returned anything like

"joyLikelihood": enum(Likelihood),
  "sorrowLikelihood": enum(Likelihood),
  "angerLikelihood": enum(Likelihood),
  "surpriseLikelihood": enum(Likelihood),
  "underExposedLikelihood": enum(Likelihood),
  **"blurredLikelihood": enum(Likelihood)**,
  "headwearLikelihood": enum(Likelihood)

I know it could not be the best way to achieve the requirement through Cloud Vision or firebase vision api's but any help or way forward is anticipated.

**Note :** Plus it Java client Library for Cloud Vision are not supported in Android.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Anyways I found the solution for the same. Though it is given in the above screenshot, that Java client libraries do not support Android but there is a workaround given here to get it running
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-google-cloud-vision-api-in-android-apps--cms-29009

Comment: hi - im looking to do the same. is it possible to do this on the device itself ? using Camerakit or CameraX apis ?

Comment: @Sandeep I am not sure of that and didn't used it. You can try and update on the same because there is no direct support of Java client library in Android.